# Нужно, чтобы элементы в RecyclerView отображались лимитировано (по 7 элементов) на одном экране, и по свайпу вправо появлялись следующие 7

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Данные для **RecyclerView** подгружаются из **Room**, и сейчас они у меня просто вертикальным списком все находятся на одном экране (это у меня **фрагмент**).

Как правильно организовать структуру отображения элементов, находящихся в **RecyclerView**, чтобы на одном экране было **всегда по 7** элементов и **по свайпу** вправо/влево появлялись следующие/предыдущие 7 элементов?
Есть мысль обернуть этот **recyclerview** во **viewpager**, но как конкретно сделать, чтобы всегда было именно 7 элементов на экране, я понять не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы банально можете реализовать sql запрос в ваш room с установленным лимитом, используя аннотацию @Query например `@Query("SELECT * FROM имя таблицы WHERE "ваше условие" LIMIT 7")`. Вы пожете задать каждому элементу порядковый номер и на каждой странице использовать `WHERE index >= 0 AND index < 7`.

Можно достать все данные из room и уже в адаптере програмно разбить на нужные участки для каждой страницы.

Можно использовать DataSource, она позволяет отдавать данные из room постранично, это я использую, когда работаю с внушительным объемом данных с тяжелым `onBindViewHolder`

Я использую устаревшую связку LivePagedListBuilder + DataSource.Factory + PagedListAdapter